# How to read chars from a file - c#

Tags: c#, file, file-io

How to read an array of numbers from a file? I mean, how to read chars from a file?

**Update:** 
Yes, I can. :) 
Just: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" and etc. I just do not know how to read chars from a file.

Comment: Can you paste an example of what the file looks like? Paste the first few lines here, for example.

Comment: A file is an array of bytes, in order to read chars you will need to know the encoding of the file. Could you post an example of a file that you are trying to read, or if it is a binary file describe its structure.

Comment: "1 2 3 123 1231 12" and etc. just numbers.

Comment: I need not be considered complete file, i need load into an array of numbers.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] numbers = File.ReadAllText("yourfile.txt").Split(' ');
```

or you could convert these to integers:

```
int[] numbers = File
    .ReadAllText("yourfile.txt")
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Well, take care for the bad integers which may throw exception.

Comment: There are cases where it's better to throw an exception to inform the user that there was something wrong while parsing the file rather than silently ignoring it. Of course this will entirely depend on the application requirements which haven't been detailed here.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not too large you can read it all into memory using for example `ReadAllLines` and then use TryParse to interpret the strings as integers. Here is some example code you could use as a starting point:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
{
    foreach (string item in line.Split(' '))
    {
        int i;
        if (!int.TryParse(item, out i))
        {
            throw new Exception("Implement error handling here");
        }

        integers.Add(i);
    }
}
```

If you know that the file will always contain valid input you can simplify this slightly by using `Parse` instead of `TryParse`.

Comment: The only answer I am gonna vote for handling exception. Good job!